# My server TCP doesn't receive messages from the client in C

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, virtual-machine

I'm beginning with network programming, so my first exercise was to create a client/server system with 2 VMs. So, I have a problem with the VMs, because they don't communicate, but if I run the code local on my machine in 2 terminal windows the code run correctly. Instead, in the VMs, the server go on "listening" but when I run the code from the client machine the server receive nothing.

Here is my server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//controllo che da riga di comando venga inserita la porta a cui collegare la     socket
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <port>", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
}
//creo tutte le variabili che mi serviranno 
int port = atoi(argv[1]); //porta presa da riga di comando
int server_sock, client_sock; //socket per server e client 
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr; //struct per gestire gli indirizzi di server e client(IPv4, IPv6)
socklen_t addr_size;    //lunghezza degli indirizzi
char buffer[1024];  //buffer per il trasferimento dei messaggi
int n;  //variabile di controllo

//chiamata alla funzione socket che restituisce un valore int a server_sock
server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
//controllo che la chiamata socket() abbia restituito un valore > 0, quindi esito della chiamata positivo
if (server_sock < 0) {
    perror("[-] Error while creating socket.\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("[+] TCP socket created. \n");
//setto i byte della memoria a 0
memset(&server_addr, '\0', sizeof(server_addr));
//assegno i vari attributi dell'indirizzo
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = port;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

//chiamata alla funzione bind che associa la socket con la porta e ne metto il valore di ritorno in n 
n = bind(server_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
//controllo che la chiamata precedente sia andata bene quindi n > 0
if (n < 0) {
    perror("[-] Error while binding the socket.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("[+] Socket binded to the port %d\n", port);

//metto in ascolto il server
listen(server_sock, 5);
printf("[+] Listening...\n");

//ciclo su i client che si collegano al server
while(1) {
    
    addr_size = sizeof(client_addr); // size dell'indirizzo del client
    //chiamata alla funzione accept, che restituisce un valore int 
    client_sock = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addr_size);
    char ipString[40]; // stringa per salvare l'ip del client che si è collegato al server
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client_addr, ipString, sizeof(client_addr)); //converto l'ip in un formato di testo
    printf("[+] Client connected.\n Client IP:%s\n", ipString); //stampo l'indirizzo che si è collegato al server

    bzero(buffer, 1024); //azzero i byte del buffer
    recv(client_sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); //ricevo il messaggio dal client
    printf("Client: %s\n", buffer); // stampo il messaggio salvato in buffer

    bzero(buffer,1024); //riazzero il buffer 
    strcpy(buffer, "Hi from the server"); // passo una stringa nel buffer
    printf("Server: %s\n", buffer); 
    send(client_sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); // mando il messaggio del buffer al client

    close(client_sock); //chiudo la connessione 
    printf("[+] Client disconnected.\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

And here the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
//controllo che la porta venga indicata in riga di comando
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <port>", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
}
//variabili di controllo, socket e indirizzo
int port = atoi(argv[1]);
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addr_size;
char buffer[1024];
int n;
//chiamata a socket e subito dopo controllo
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock < 0) {
    perror("[-] Error while creating socket.\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("[+] TCP socket created. \n");
memset(&addr, '\0', sizeof(addr));//setto i byte a 0
//imposto gli attributi dell'indirizzo
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = port;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
//connetto la socket
int tmp;
tmp = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
if (tmp < 0) {
    perror(“Error while connecting.”);
    exit(1); }
printf("[+] Client connected.\n");

bzero(buffer, 1024);// azzero i byte del buffer
strcpy(buffer, "Hello World");
printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); // mando il messaggio contenuto nel buffer

bzero(buffer, 1024);
recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); //ricevo la risposta del server 
printf("Server: %s\n", buffer);

close(sock); // chiudo la connessione lato client
printf("[+] Disconnected from the server");

return 0;
}
```

I get the error in the connect function, but I don’t know what’s wrong with it.

Comment: If the code works on a single machine, but not between the two VMs, have you considered the possibility that the network between the two VMs is not set up correctly? Can the two VMs actually reach each other? Try to check with simple tools like netcat. Can you run `nc -lp 12345` on a machine to listen and then `nc <other_ip> 12345` on the second mathine to connect to the first and send data?

Comment: What error did you get, from where? Without any error checking in `connect()` you can’t possibly debug this. Ditto `listen(), accept(), send(), recv().`